# Liapunov function for the van der Pol oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, biology, lyapunov-functions

i have attempted this question and done as much as i possibly could, any help regarding this question would be very helpful and appreciated.

a) show that the second-order differential equation for the van der pol oscillator, that is

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\beta (x^2-1) \frac{dx}{dt}+x=0    $$

where $\beta$ is a constant parameter, is equivalent to the following first order system in the plane

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=y, \qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=-x+\beta (1-x^2)y.   $$

b) find the unique steady state for the system, and perform linearization around this steady state in order to determine its stability.

c) show in the case $\beta <0$ that $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is a weak liapunov function for the system, in the sense that $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is negative definate.  demonstrate also that in the case,

$$W(x,y)=(2+\beta^2)x^2-2\beta xy+2y^2,   $$

is a strong liapunov function by showing there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that in the region when $|x|,|y|<\epsilon$, $\frac{dW}{dt}$ is negative definate. what about the case $\beta>0$? can you apply the poincare-bendixson theorem in the latter case?

This is what i have tried to attempt so far:

a) do i have to substitue $\frac{dx}{dt}=y$ here? i have tried this but dont really know how it gets to the equations above..,

b)steady state = $(0,0)$ with associated linear system:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=y, \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = -x + \beta y    $$

and so

$$A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  -1 & \beta   
 \end{pmatrix}    $$

which gives:

$$\lambda= \frac{\beta \pm \sqrt{(\beta^2-4)}}{2}    $$

thus the origin is an unstable spiral if $0<\beta<2$ and an unstable node if $\beta>2$

c) $$\frac{dV}{dt} = xy+y(-x+\beta (1-x^2)y)   $$

$$ = 1-x^2$$

hence $\frac{dV}{dt} \leq 0$ if $x^2<1$ and $\beta <0$ and is stable

and $\frac{dV}{dt} \geq 0$ if $x^2<1$ and $\beta >0$ and is unstable

taking $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and the domain $x^2+y^2<1$ then the origin is stable if $\beta <0$ and unstable if $\beta >0$

is this right so far? not sure on how to do the $W(x,y)$ part.

many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, since it is asked 6 years ago, however:

a) Transform the differential equation to a state-space model; use auxilary variable $y$ (state)

$y = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$

Thus,

$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$

Then just rewrite the equation as two first order differential equations:

$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = y$

$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}  =\right) −x+\beta(1−x^2)y.$

b) Solve for all the derivatives w.r.t. time equal to zero (no change w.r.t. time means states are fixed for all time)